# Button Event not Triggering After Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm working on a Kirby site and I followed the ['Load More'](https://getkirby.com/docs/cookbook/templating/ajax-load-more) tutorial for a website blog I am working on. Everything is working; however, I am also using an AJAX call for my parent pages. (I'm using swup library).

Normally, I would bind an event after an AJAX request to the document using .on() in jQuery; however, I can't seem to figure out how to do the same within the template/new.js file in pure Javascript.

**Here's my code as per the tutorial:**

```
const element = document.querySelector('.articles');
const button = document.querySelector('.load-more');
let page = parseInt(element.getAttribute('data-page'));

console.log(element.getAttribute('data-page'))

const fetchArticles = async () => {
    let url = 'news.json/page:2';

    try {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const {
            html,
            more
        } = await response.json();
        button.hidden = !more;
        element.innerHTML += html;
        page++;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Fetch error: ', error);
    }
}

button.addEventListener('click', fetchArticles);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: A little more info would be helpful. Where does this JS get executed on your page? You must wait for `DOMContentLoaded` before attempting to select an element and bind an event to it.

Comment: @daddygames Thanks for the reply – the JS gets loaded in the footer.

This the above code works perfectly when the load the /news page but if I navigation from /about > /news, for example, the content is loaded using AJAX and now when I try to trigger the .load-more it doesn't work.

Normally I'd use JQuery on() method but I've done this with just vanilla JS. 

Thanks again.